Contour integral of complex conjugate function. Doubt about result in Visual Complex Analysis book
In the book "Visual Complex Analysis", in chapter 8 section 5.2. the book shows:
$\oint\limits_{L}\bar{z}dz = 2i(area\space enclosed)$
where L is a closed path.
An then shows a simple example:
Consider a circle C of radius r centered at a, the equation of which is $r^2=|z-a|^2=(z-a)(\bar{z}-\bar{a})$.
Then it says: Solving for $\bar{z}$, and using the fact that:
$\oint\limits_{L}\frac{1}{z-p}dz=2\pi iv(L, p).$ where v(L, p) is the winding number.
we find that:
$\oint\limits_{C}\bar{z}dz=\bar{a}\oint\limits_{C}dz+r^2\oint\limits_{C}\frac{1}{z-a}dz$
and then proceeds with:
$= 0 + r^22\pi i = 2i(area \space enclosed)$ (This step I understand, it's the previous one the one I do not follow)
I understand that when solving for $\bar{z}$ you get the equation $\bar{z}=\frac{r^2}{z-a}+\bar{a}$.
From here I don't understand how one can transform this equaion into the above equality with contour integrals on both sides.It's like we are applying the integral operator along the curve C to both sides of the equation which does not make sense to me.
Could someone explain what fundamental issue I am missing? How does one go from the equation for the circle centered around a with radius r to the equation with contour integrals on both sides?
Thank you very much.

Integrals are linear? If I have $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$, then it is certainly true that $\int f = \int g + h = \int g + \int h$. Separately what may be confusing you is that on the contour, you can swap out exactly that relationship that describes the circle. That is how all "embedded" integrals (line integrals, surface integrals, etc) work.

I understand the linearity of integrals. What do you mean exactly with the second point? Maybe that is indeed what I am missing.

For example, if I wanted to integrate the surface integral $\int_S x^2+y^2+z^2:dS$ on the sphere $S:x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$, I only care about integrating over the set where $x,y,z$ satisfy that restriction exactly i.e. only the surface, not the interior nor exterior. So I can rewrite the integral as $$\int_S x^2+y^2+z^2:dS = \int_Sr^2:dS = 4\pi r^4$$

Similarly, you only care about the $z$ and $\bar{z}$ that satisfy that restriction (equation) of the complex plane to just that curve $C$. No other points except the ones in $C$ are included in the integration, so you can always use the restriction (equation) to rewrite the integral with an equivalent integrand, even if the two integrands are only equivalent on the set $C$

That is it, how dumb of me. Thank you sir. If you want to write this as an answer I will accept it as the correct one.

What may be confusing you is that on the contour, you can swap out exactly that relationship that describes the circle. That is how all "embedded" integrals (line integrals, surface integrals, etc) work.
For example, if I wanted to integrate the surface integral $\int_S x^2+y^2+z^2\:d$S
on the sphere $S:x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$
, I only care about integrating over the set where $x,y,z$
satisfy that restriction exactly i.e. only the surface, not the interior nor the exterior. So I can rewrite the integral as
$$\int_S x^2+y^2+z^2\:dS=\int_Sr^2\:dS=4πr^4$$
Similarly, you only care about the $z$
and $\bar{z}$
that satisfy that restriction (equation) of the complex plane to just that curve $C$. No other points except the ones in $C$
are included in the integration, so you can always use the restriction (equation) to rewrite the integral with an equivalent integrand, even if the two integrands are only equivalent on the set $C$.
